# Transmitting Byte Array through UDP Windows Phone C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sockets, udp

I am trying to transmit data through UDP protocol on windows phone. Here is the code-

```
_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        if (_socket != null)
        {

            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint("CompName", 11000);

            byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("String Payload");

            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(newtest, 0, newtest.Length);

            _socket.SendToAsync(socketEventArg);
        }
```

This code is working perfectly fine when I am sending a string. However, when I replace this byte array with data from a Camera Preview, like this -

```
 cam.GetPreviewBufferYCbCr(payload);
```

where cam is a properly initialized PhotoCamera object, the following two errors are generated and the transmission is not working.

*A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Net.dll*

*A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Net.dll*

I tested and made sure that this is not a problem with the larger byte array size. Any pointers in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I discovered from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx that an InvalidCastException is generated when there is a failure in an explicit reference conversion. Since I am not converting anything here by myself, I am pretty sure that the error is being generated by the socket itself.

Comment: The error occurs on which line?

Comment: I am unable to tell exactly because it is a first chance exception, that is, one that is handled automatically before it occurs.

Comment: Can you provide the full callstack of the InvalidCastException then? Also, are you sure the `cam.GetPreviewBufferYCbCr(payload);` is the only line that differs from your example?

Comment: I solved the problem by splitting the byte array into chunks of 1024 bytes each and then transmitting them. I am note sure why it works, but it does.  @KooKiz Thanks for trying to help. I will post the original Stack Trace later if possible.